# Linux Sqliteman all buttons and tabs come up as disabled after installation configuration help needed?

Tags: sql, linux, sqlite

I installed Sqlite 3.8 on Ubuntu 13 and I installed sqliteman for a GUI.

I got Sqliteman using Ubuntu Software Center, but after the installation completes, Sqliteman starts up but I can't click on anything cause everything in the application is disabled.

I'm assuming there is some sort of configuration step I am missing but I cannot find anything online to tell me what I'm missing.

If anybody knows what I can do I would appreciate some assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  First of all I had to install Qt 4 for linux.

After I did this it still wasn't working and still had everything greyed out.  So I signed in as root user i.e sudo su and then Sqliteman works fine with root permissions.

Cheers